# Lazy load Storyboard static UITableView cells

Tags: ios, storyboard, lazy-loading

I am creating a table view in story board based mainly on static cells.
Is there any approach to lazy load the data in the cells, I will explain.

Let's say that the last cell, that is not visible to the users before they scroll the table view. This cell has an imageView that loads an image fro the server. What I want is to load the images only if the user is scrolling to this cell.

Any idea

Thanks
Shani

Comment: what method is using for loading image.

Answer (score 0):

You may start loading the image in the `UITableViewDelegate` method `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`.